# How do I change all negative numbers to zero in python?

Tags: python, list

I have one list

```
    list1 = [-10,1,2,3,9,-1]
```

I want to change the negative number to zero so that it looks like

```
    list1 = [0,1,2,3,9,0]
```

how can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: This is not really a duplicate question. The supposed duplicate is asking about the absolute value, not changing negatives to 0. The answers may have a similar approach, but that does not make the question a duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use comprehensions:

```
list2 = [0 if i < 0 else i for i in list1]
```

or

```
list2 = [(i > 0) * i for i in list1]
```

Note that the second variant only works with Python 3 since `True == 1` and `False == 0`. It *should* work with Python 2 but there is no guarantee.

Answer (score 5):

You can alternatively use the `map` function

```
map(lambda x: max(x,0),list1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to is numpy like this:

```
list2 = numpy.array(list1)
list2 = list2 * (list2 >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list and if it's less that 0 change it

```
def do_the_thing(old_list):
    new_list = []
    for num in old_list:
        if num < 0:
             new_list.append(0)
        else:
            new_list.append(num)
    return new_list
```